# TYPO3 11.5.17 with PostgreSQL 14.5

Tags: postgresql, typo3

I am trying to install TYPO3 11.5.17 with PostgreSQL 14.5. I tried to follow [this](https://t3planet.com/blog/typo3-postgresql/) guide, but in step 2, only MySQL options are shown for me. This is a discrepancy to the screenshot. I tried to troubleshoot this, but pages like [this](https://docs.typo3.org/p/friendsoftypo3/dbal/8.4/en-us/Appendices/UsingPostgresqlWithTypo3/InstallingAndConfiguringAdodbAndDbal/Index.html) are written for outdated versions. I could not find newer pages that are saying anything else than "it works with PostgreSQL". However, I am obviously missing something that needs to be done. As all pages that help troubleshooting this issue are written for versions with different file structure, I am out of ideas now. How can I get PostgreSQL to show up in the installer?

Followup question: I was not too happy about the idea to run two separate DBMSs on one server. PostgreSQL is already needed for other services. However, if anybody can come up with a good point about why TYPO3 runs much much better with MySQL, I will consider this new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you missed the needed PHP Database Extensions to handle postgreSQL?

see the [System requirements](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/SystemRequirements/Index.html#required-database-extensions) regarding the needed extensions.

Comment: This is correct, thank you. However, I like to add the following information: At first, I did not grasp that it is not a Typo3 extension I need, but a PHP extension. For Ubuntu Server 22.04, I installed the package php-pgsql using apt-get.